# Change from qwerty to number keyboard android

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to @Override the behavoir of the change keyboard button in Android. I want to change from the querty keyboard to a number keyboard(only numbers).

I need the both keyboards, to text something like KFRS87587.

From this:
[image: QWERTY Keyboard]

To this:
[image: number keyboard]

how can i do it?

Thanks to everyone! And sorry about my English!

Comment: "I want to @Override the behavoir of the change keyboard button in Android" -- that is not possible, short of creating a custom ROM. If you want one of *your* `EditText` widgets to have a certain soft keyboard structure, you can use `android:inputType` and related attributes, per Actiwitty's answer.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, I need the both keyboards. I´ll edit the quiestion now!

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

to your EditText xml

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, I need the both keyboards. I´ll edit the quiestion now!

Comment: You can just do android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789" and add any character you wish.

Comment: Not... but thank you! i want to change the keyboard, your code avoid to enter number or digits wich aren´t in android:digits

Answer (score 0):

The switch from QWERTY to numpad, you would call the following method & parameter.

```
EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I´l try it and tell you the result!